# Charging a spherical conducting shell

Tags: potential-energy

An isolated conducting spherical shell carries a negative charge. What will happen if a positively charged metal object is placed in contact with the shell interior ?. Assume that the positive charge is (a) less than, (b) equal to, and (c) grater than the negative charge in magnitude.

This is a conceptual question which shouldn't require any mathematical operation.  I understand that the electrons will gather inside the shell in contact with the positive charge, if the positive charge is greater than the negative charge. However, I can't figure what will happen if both charges are equal, or the positive charge is smaller than the negative charge. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outside of the shell becomes charged with the majority charges so if there are more negative charges than positive charges the outside of the shell will become negatively charged, or uncharged if the positive and negative charges are equal.

There will be no net charge inside the conducting shell or on the inner surface of the conducting shell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Farcher. I am having a little trouble with visualising the situation. I tried to find a video that depics this, however I got confused even more. Doesn't your explanation contradict to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXMAvaJ-Ccc (7th minute), where it says the outer surface will have positive charge? This video is about induction, not conduction and I'm not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: Also if the neutrons move to the outer surface if the total charge in the shell is negative, doesn't the lack of negative charges on the inner surface of the shell cause a positive charge on the inner surface?

Comment: No.  The bound electrons and the nuclei do not move.  It is only the free (mobile) electrons which move.  A positive charge on the outside of the conducting shell is a lack of free elections.  In electrostatics when you draw diagrams with positive charges moving in a particular direction it is actually electrons moving the opposite direction.

Comment: Ok but in this case, how do you describe the change on the inside of the shell if the outside of the shell will become negatively charged due to the majority of negative charges in the shell?

Comment: I should have said how do you describe the change on the inner surface of the shell.

Comment: Equal numbers of positive charges (protons) and negative (all electrons) charges.

Comment: I apologise but one last question... The net charge inside the shell will be positive if the positive charge from the metal  is greater than the negative charge of the shell, which is the only case when the net charge of the shell will not be zero, is this correct?

Comment: Whichever is the excess charge it will reside on the outside surface of the conducting shell.  There will be no net charge inside the conducting shell and on the inside surface of the conducting shell.